# How to automatically pair Bluetooth device

Tags: android

I'm creating an android application.

I want to be able to automatically connect to nearby device(s) without manually having to go through the pairing process.

Is there any way to by-pass the pairing process?
I'm using `device.createBond()`

Comment: No user is on first priority . user permission is must .

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

There is no way to bypass authorisation of the user; it is a mandatory step for privacy reasons.

---

Below is an [excerpt](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) from the [Android Developer's site](https://developer.android.com) on permissions;

> The purpose of a permission is to protect the privacy of an Android user. Android apps must request permission to access sensitive user data (such as contacts and SMS), as well as certain system features (such as camera and internet). Depending on the feature, the system might grant the permission automatically or might prompt the user to approve the request.
>
> A central design point of the Android security architecture is that no app, by default, has permission to perform any operations that would adversely impact other apps, the operating system, or the user. This includes reading or writing the user's private data (such as contacts or emails), reading or writing another app's files, performing network access, keeping the device awake, and so on.
>
> This page provides an overview to how Android permissions work, including: how permissions are presented to the user, the difference between install-time and runtime permission requests, how permissions are enforced, and the types of permissions and their groups. If you just want a how-to guide for using app permissions, instead see [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).